# ElasticSearch RegExp Filter regex dash

Tags: regex, lucene, elasticsearch

I have a few documents in my ElasticSearch v1.2.1 like:

```
{
  "tempSkipAfterSave": "false",
  "variation": null,
  "images": null,
  "name": "Dolce & Gabbana Short Sleeve Coat",
  "sku": "MD01575254-40-WHITE",
  "user_id": "123foo",
  "creation_date": null,
  "changed": 1
}
```

where `sku` can be a variation such as : `MD01575254-40-BlUE`, `MD01575254-38-WHITE`

I can get my elastic search query to work with this:

```
{
  "size": 1000,
  "from": 0,
  "filter": {
    "and": [
      {
        "regexp": {
          "sku": "md01575254.*"
        }
      },
      {
        "term": {
          "user_id": "123foo"
        }
      },
      {
        "missing": {
          "field": "project_id"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "query": {
    "match_all": {}
  }
}
```

I got all the variations back of sku: `MD01575254*`

However, the dash '-' is really screwing me up

when I change the regexp to:

```
"regexp": {
  "sku": "md01575254-40.*"
}
```

I can't get any results back. I've also tried

- "sku": "md01575254-40.*"
- "sku": "md01575254\-40.*"
- "sku": "md01575254-40-.*"
- ...

Just can't seem to make it work ? What am I don't wrong here?

Comment: use any JSON parsing library.

Comment: put `-` inside char class like `[-]`

Comment: this was actually generated from a json parsing library and 

[-] does not work

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Problem:**

This is because the default analyzer usually tokenizes at `-`, so your field is most likey saved like:

- `MD01575254`
- `40`
- `BlUE`

---

**Solution:**

You can update your mapping to have a `sku.raw` field that would not be analyzed when indexed.  This will require you to delete and re-index.

```
{
  "<type>" : {
    "properties" : {
      ...,
      "sku" : {
        "type": "string",
        "fields" : {
          "raw" : {"type" : "string", "index" : "not_analyzed"}
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Then you can query this new field which is not analyzed:

```
{
  "query" : {
    "regexp" : {
      "sku.raw": "md01575254-40.*"
    }
  }
}
```

---

**HTTP Endpoints:**

The API to delete your current mapping and data is:

```
DELETE http://localhost:9200/<index>/<type>
```

The API to add your new mapping, with the raw SKU is:

```
PUT http://localhost:9200/<index>/<type>/_mapping
```

---

**Links:**

- [multiple fields in mapping](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-core-types.html#_updating_a_field)
- [analyzers](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-analyzers.html)

Comment: thank you for the helpful answer, i was actually just searching the elasticsearch github bugs list, and started going down the path of analyzed vs non

Comment: Glad I could help :) I've had the same issues when creating facets (now called aggregations, in 1.*).

Comment: Damned ! You saved us ! :)

Answer (score 3):

This can also we achieved by the following query. (use `.keyword` next to the field)

```
"regexp": {
"sku.keyword": "md01575254-40.*"
}
```

Comment: This helps me. Thank you.