# regex breaks when I use a colon(:)

Tags: regex, elasticsearch

I just started working with elastic search. By started working I mean I have to query an already running elastic database.  Is there a good documentation of the regex they follow. I know about the one on their official site, but its not very helpful.

The more specific problem is that I want to query for lines of the sort:

`10:02:37:623421|0098-TSOT {TRANSITION} {ID} {1619245525} {securityID} {} {fromStatus} {NOT_PRESENT} {toStatus} {WAITING}`

or

`01:01:36:832516|0058-CT {ADD} {0} {3137TTDR7} {23} {COM} {New} {0} {0} {52} {1}`

and more of a similar structure. I don't want a generalized regex. If possible, could someone give me a regex expression for each of these that would run with elastic?

I noticed that it matches if the regexp matches with a substring too when I ran with:

```
query = {"query":
             {"regexp":
                  {
                      "message": "[0-9]{2}"
                  }
              },
         "sort":
             [
                 {"@timestamp":"asc"}
             ]
         }
```

But it wont match anything if I use:

```
query = {"query":
             {"regexp":
                  {
                      "message": "[0-9]{2}:.*"
                  }
              },
         "sort":
             [
                 {"@timestamp":"asc"}
             ]
         }
```

I want to write regex that are more specific and that are different for the two examples given near the top.

Comment: I question whether your first regex `[0-9]{2}` actually matched anything at all.  Rather, `[0-9]{2}:.*` should in fact have matched your message lines.athe

Comment: the first one matched everything, and the second one didn't match anything. I know this sounds strange, that's why I'm asking this here.

Comment: have you tried using `message.keyword` instead of `message` as field name ?

Comment: the field im trying to query is "message". But just to be safe I tried adding a ```.keyword```. now nothing matches.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [ElasticSearch RegExp Filter regex dash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24940112/elasticsearch-regexp-filter-regex-dash)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

turns out my message is present in the tokenized form instead of the raw form, and `:` is one of the default delimiters of the tokenizer, in elastic. And as a reason, I can't use regexp query on the whole message because it matches it with each token individually.